# How to create Haskell function that returns every third element from a list of ints

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to create a function that returns every third int from a list of ints without using any predefined functions. For example, `everyThird [1,2,3,4,5] --> [1,4]`

```
everyThird:: [a] -> [a]
```

Could I just continue to iterate over the list using tail and appending to a new list every third call? I am new to Haskell and very confused with all of this

Comment: As a thumb rule, you should avoid `head,tail`, and prefer pattern matching as done by the answer below.

Comment: I will try and remember that, thank you. This is my first time working in Haskell, so I am just now learning how some of these things work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do exactly what you said: iterate over the list and include the element only on each third call. However, there's a problem. Haskell is a funny language where the idea of "changing" a variable doesn't make sense, so the usual approach of "have a counter variable `i` which tells us whether we're on the third element or not" won't work in the usual way. Instead, we'll create a recursive helper function to maintain the count for us.

```
everyThird :: [Int] -> [Int]
everyThird xs = helper 0 xs
  where helper _ [] = []
        helper 0 (x : xs) = x : helper 2 xs
        helper n (_ : xs) = helper (n - 1) xs
```

We have three cases in the helper.

1. If the list is empty, stop and return the empty list.
2. If the counter is at 0 (that is, if we're on the third element), make a list starting with the current element and ending with the rest of the computation.
3. If the counter is not at zero, count down and continue iteration.

Because of the way pattern matching works, it will try these three statements in order.

Notice how we use an additional argument to be the counter variable since we can't mutate the variable like we would in an imperative language. Also, notice how we construct the list recursively; we never "append" to an existing list because that would imply that we're mutating the list. We simply build the list up from scratch and end up with the correct result on the first go round.

Comment: So, when you call everyThird xs = helper 0 xs, you are calling a helper function (helper) that checks for those three cases? And then returns the list that is left when it has all been checked?

Comment: Exactly. And note that `helper` calls itself to get the rest of the list. Thinking recursively like this is how Haskell works, and it helps you compartmentalize the problem by dealing with only one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there anyway to re-write this without using where? Or other things such as let?

Comment: You can replace most any recursive function with a fairly complicated `fix` call, but that would just be slightly overkill. Why do you want to avoid the declaration of local variables/functions?

Comment: I am trying to get a feel for the language without using any tools or helpers, it helps to get a better understanding as to what is going on.

Comment: `where`/`let` is the equivalent of declaring a local variable in any other language. It's really very fundamental to the language. But if you want to save such constructs for later, you could define `helper` as a global function and then call it.

Comment: Thank you, I think I solved it, and I appreciate your insight!

Answer (score 9):

One other way of doing this is to handle three different base cases, in all of which we're at the end of the list and the list is less than three elements long, and one recursive case, where the list is at least three elements long:

```hs
everyThird :: [a] -> [a]
everyThird []         = []
everyThird [x]        = [x]
everyThird [x, _]     = [x]
everyThird (x:_:_:xs) = x:everyThird xs
```

Answer (score 5):

Haskell doesn't have classical iteration (i.e. no loops), at least not without monads, but you can use similar logic as you would in a for loop by zipping your list with indexes `[0..]` and applying appropriate functions from Data.List.

E.g. What you need to do is filter every third element:

```
everyThirdWithIndexes list = filter (\x -> snd x `mod` 3 == 0) $ zip list [0..]
```

Of course you have to get rid of the indexes, there are two elegant ways you can do this:

```
everyThird list = map (fst) . everyThirdWithIndexes list
-- or:
everyThird list = fst . unzip . everyThirdWithIndexes list
```

If you're not familiar with filter and map, you can define a simple recursion that builds a list from every first element of a list, drops the next two and then adds another from a new function call:

```
everyThird [] = []  -- both in case if the list is empty and the end case
everyThird (x:xs) = x : everyThird (drop 2 xs)
```

EDIT: If you have any questions about these solutions (e.g. some syntax that you are not familiar with), feel free to ask in the comments. :)

Comment: So referring to the last part of your post, calling everyThird[] = [] will check if the list is empty, and if it is will return an empty list? Then the next call (everyThird (x:xs) = x :everyThird (drop 2xs) will take the list, drop the first two ints from it, and append the next one? I am new to Haskell and this all seems like wizardry to me

Comment: Yes, maybe an example will help. Let's say we have `[1,2,3,4,5]`. The list isn't empty so it matches the second expression and builds `1:everyThird(drop 2 [2,3,4,5])` which evaluates to `1:everyThird([4,5])`. Ok, great, we have the first element, in the second call we build a similar expression and append it to the first one, so something like `1:4:everyThird(drop 2 [5])` is generated. Dropping two from `[5]`generates an empty list which matches the first function definition so the final expression is `1:4:[]` which is the same as `[1,4]` (the latter is just syntactic sugar)

Comment: That example helped a ton, I was not quite sure how it was working in the beginning and now it is much more clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your Haskell studying, and don't worry - a lot of things in Haskell take some time to sink in :)

Answer (score 5):

One classic approach:

```
everyThird xs = [x | (1,x) <- zip (cycle [1..3]) xs]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`chunksOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) from `Data.List.Split` to seperate the lists into chunks of 3, then just map the first element of each:

```
import Data.List.Split

everyThird :: [a] -> [a]
everyThird xs = map head $ chunksOf 3 xs
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> everyThird [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,4]
```

**Note:** You may need to run `cabal install split` to use `chunksOf`.

Comment: He didn't want to use pre-defined functions. Apart from that a good answer.